# Prove $\log_n(2) + \log_2(3) + \log_3(4) + \log_4(5) + \cdots + \log_{n-1}(n) > n-1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a silly question, but I tried a little things here and I only managed to write

$$\log_n(2) + \log_2(3) + \log_3(4) + \log_4(5) + \cdots + \log_{n-1}(n) > \log_n(n!)$$

Comment: Is this for $n\geq3$? I'm not sure how to interpret the left side for $n=2$.

Comment: Which is your question?  You gave us two different inequalities.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?  Once you prove it is true for $\log_3(2) + \log_2(3)$ you'll find the rest of the proof only depends on $n-1 \lt n$

Comment: In fact, the second inequality (with $[\ldots]>\log_n(n!)$) is very easy and doesn't need AM-GM.  It follows from $\ln(n)>\ln(k)$ for all $k=2,3,\ldots,n-1$.  (EDT:  Just realized that Laplacian Fourier also gave a similar hint.)

Answer (score 4):

Hint...write each log in the form $$\frac{\ln p}{\ln q}$$ and apply AM-GM inequality

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Expand the RHS into a sum of logs, then use the fact that $\log_b(x)>\log_n(x)$ for $b<n$ to prove that each individual term is smaller than the corresponding one on the LHS.